# Make R/lubridate consistently output in days

Tags: r, date, time, dplyr, lubridate

I'm working with dates, and I want to make a column that says how many days until an event occurs. I then want to filter on the number of days. I've noticed that lubridate occasionally changes the unit on me (sometimes days, sometimes hours), so I want to make my code explicit that I want it in days.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
problem <- tibble(location = c("Atlanta, GA", "New York City, NY", "San Francisco, CA"),
                  travel_date = ymd_hms(c("2018-12-17 02:30:00", "2019-7-17 02:30:00", "2020-12-20 09:30:00")))
```

To make it explicit that I want the unit in days, I've tried using round_date():

```
problem %>%
  mutate(days_to_deadline = round_date(travel_date - now(), unit = "day")) %>%
  filter(days_to_deadline <= 100 & days_to_deadline >= 0)
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(x) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXct”
```

In this instance, this code works:

```
problem %>%
  mutate(days_to_deadline = round(travel_date - now())) %>%
  filter(days_to_deadline <= days(50) & days_to_deadline >= 0)
```

But again, I've seen the units change based on what's being fed in, so I want to guarantee that R is reading this in days and not any other unit of time.

Comment: could you just use difftime function to get difference between travel_date and today(), and specify units = "days"? in this case, it would give number of periods of 24 hours; let me know if this is helpful

Comment: @Ben, I never knew of this function! Yes, it 100% solved my issue--thanks!